# Generic protocol extension and `Self`

Tags: swift, generics

I have a protocol that defines the ability to fetch an array of objects from a server. `Result` is defined in [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/swift-2.0/Source/Result.swift):

```
protocol BulkFetchable {

    static func fetch(limit : Int, skip : Int, completionHandler : ((request : NSURLRequest?, response : NSHTTPURLResponse?, result : Result<[Self]?>) -> Void)) -> Request

}
```

I extend this protocol with a generic implementation (ignore the fact that that the endpoint is fixed for the purposes of this question):

```
extension BulkFetchable where Self : Mappable {

    static func fetch(limit: Int, skip: Int, completionHandler: ((request: NSURLRequest?, response: NSHTTPURLResponse?, result: Result<[Self]?>) -> Void)) -> Request {
        return Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://localhost:4567/users.json", parameters: ["limit" : limit, "skip" : skip], encoding: .URL, headers: nil).responseArray(completionHandler)
    }

}
```

I'm using an extension to Alamofire `Request` that converts a JSON response to an optional array of type `T`, where `T` adopts `Mappable`:

```
extension Request {

func responseArray <T : Mappable> (completionHandler: (NSURLRequest?, NSHTTPURLResponse?, Result<[T]?>) -> Void) -> Self {
    return responseJSON(completionHandler: { (req, res, result) -> Void in
        switch result {
        case .Success(let json):
            completionHandler(req, res, .Success(Mapper<T>().mapArray(json)))
            break
        case .Failure(let data, let error):
            completionHandler(req, res, .Failure(data,error))
            break
        }
    })
}

}
```

Then, I give my `User` model this ability:

```
extension User : BulkFetchable {}
```

Alas, I receive the error:

> Protocol 'BulkFetchable' requirement
>   'fetch(_:skip:completionHandler:)' cannot be satisfied by a non-final
>   class ('User') because it uses 'Self' in a non-parameter, non-result
>   type position

What can I do to get around this? I would expect that `Self` automatically becomes `User` in the context of the extension to `User`, but that's probably due to my lack of understanding.

Comment: What is Result<[Self]? on Generic parameter ? How does that even compile ?

Comment: Hi @GeneratorOfOne, I've added more context. It doesn't compile – hence the question!

Comment: `Result` in Alamofire is a Generic with 2 params, not 1, no? `public enum Result<Value, Error: ErrorType>`

Comment: Thanks @Brynjar, but this was using the previous release of Alamofire which had a different Result struct.

Answer (score 6):

I was doing something similar and stumbled on the same error.

My limited understanding of this (which comes mostly from two videos recorded at WWDC 2015 [here](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-414/) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-408/)) suggests that your class User needs to be declared as:

**`final class User {...}`**

This would be because the `fetch()` call doesn't have to be overridden by a subclass.

`fetch()` is supposed to return a homogenous array of Self (in this case `User`) and if `User` was subclassed (and `fetch()` overriden) it would return an array of the subclass. Or in an easily imagined world an array of `User` and its subclasses. Not what the super class `BulkFetchable` was expecting!